# Recursive function loops infinitely

Tags: php, recursion, artificial-intelligence

I am working on a personal project, a bot that plays connect 4. So something is seriously wrong with the recursive function I have written to manage the bots move. No errors are thrown, and any debug info I can be shown does not tell me anything useful. Additionally, I am sure that I have not overflown my stack and that my php.ini file is good to go. This script just runs (consumes a sane amount of memory) and never returns. Only about 2400 function calls should be happening, so this script should return after only a second or two. This has stumped me for days. I believe there is something I have not properly researched. Additonally I should mention that the game board is a simple 2D array to simulate a 7 x 7 board. `ai_move_helper` is the recursive function and I just cannot figure out why it will not function correctly.

```
// this class is a code igniter library
class ConnectFour
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // these are expensive opperations this will give the server enough time
        set_time_limit(0);
        ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');
    }

    public $board_width     = 7;
    public $board_length    = 7;
    public $game_array      = array();
    public $depth_limit     = 3;

            // this function gets a human made move from a CI controller ($game board)
            // and returns the board after the new AI move is applied
    public function ai_player_move($game_array, $active_players_move)
    {
        $this->game_array = $game_array;            
        $this->game_array = $this->calculate_ai_move($active_players_move);
        return $this->game_array;   
    }

    public function calculate_ai_move($active_players_move)
    {
        $move_weight_array = array();
        $prime_game_board = array();

        // we hardcast the active player because at this point we know it is the AI
        // here we also have to prime the move computer
        for($q = 0; $q < $this->board_length; $q++)
        {
            // MAGIC NUMBERS are the active players!!!
            $prime_game_board[] = $this->apply_prime_move($q, 2, $this->game_array);

            $move_weight_array[] = $this->ai_move_helper($prime_game_board[$q], 2, 0);  
        }

        //choose your move
        for($u = 0; $u < $this->board_length; $u)
        {
            if($move_weight_array[$u][0] == 1)
            {
                return $prime_game_board[$u];               
            }
        }

        // otherwise return a random acceptable move
        $random = rand(0, 6);
        return $prime_game_board[$random];

    }

    public function ai_move_helper($game_board, $active_player, $depth)
    {
        // build the object that will be needed at this level of recusion
        $depth = $depth + 1;
        $score_object                               = new stdClass;
        $move_array                                 = array();
        $game_boards_generated_at_this_level        = array(); 
        $new_game_boards_generated_at_this_level    = array();
        $return_end_state_detected                  = 0;
        $score_agregate                             = array();          

        if($this->depth_limit < $depth)
        {
            $score_agregate[0] = 0; 
            $score_agregate[1] = 0;
            return $score_agregate; 
        }

        $active_player = ($active_player == 1) ? 2 : 1;

        // check for possible moves
        for($i=0; $i < $this->board_width; $i++)
        {
            // calculate all of the possible recusions (all of the next moves)
            $game_boards_generated_at_this_level[$i] = $this->apply_ai_move($i, $active_player, $game_board);
            // this is the recusive level
            $score_agregate = $this->ai_move_helper($game_boards_generated_at_this_level[$i]->game_board, $active_player, $depth);              
        }

        // check to see if there are more moves of if it is time to return
        foreach($game_boards_generated_at_this_level as $game_state)
        {
            //compute the agragate of the scores only for player two (AI)
            if($active_player == 2)
            {
                $score_agregate[0] = $score_agregate[0] + $game_state->score_array[0]; 
                $score_agregate[1] = $score_agregate[1] + $game_state->score_array[1];              
            }
        }

        return $score_agregate;
    }

    public function apply_ai_move($move, $active_players_move, $board_to_use)
    {
        $board_for_function     = array();
        $location_of_new_pieces = 0;
        $return_object          = new stdClass;

        // this makes sure that this function is being called with the right board
        if(!empty($board_to_use))
        {
            $board_for_function = $board_to_use;
        } else {
            $board_for_function = $this->game_array;
        }

        // check that this move is possible
        if(!$this->move_possible($move, $board_for_function))
        {
            $return_object->game_board      = NULL;
            $return_object->score_array     = NULL;
            return $return_object;
        }

        // this part of the function applies a valid move
        foreach($board_for_function[$move] as $column_key => $column_space)
        {
            // check if you are at the edge of an empty row
            if(!array_key_exists(($location_of_new_pieces + 1), $board_for_function[$move]) && $column_space == '_')
            {
                $board_for_function[$move][$location_of_new_pieces] = ($active_players_move == 1) ? 'x' : 'o';
                break;
            }

            // check if the next place has stuff in it too
            if($column_space != '_')
            {
                // check the edge of the board to make sure that exists
                if(array_key_exists(($location_of_new_pieces - 1), $board_for_function))
                {
                    $board_for_function[$move][$location_of_new_pieces - 1] = ($active_players_move == 1) ? 'x' : 'o';
                    break;
                } else {
                    echo "well fuck...1"; exit;
                }
            }

            $location_of_new_pieces++;
        }

        $return_object->game_board = $board_for_function;

        // now check if this state is a win loss or draw
        $test_for_complete = $this->check_for_winner_or_draw($board_for_function, $active_players_move);

        // this is a draw
        if($test_for_complete == -1)
        {
            $return_object->score_array = array(0, 1);
        } else if($test_for_complete > 3) {
            $return_object->score_array = array(1, 0);
        } else {
            $return_object->score_array = array(0, 0);
        }

        return $return_object;
    }

    public function apply_prime_move($move, $active_players_move, $board_to_use)
    {
        $location_of_new_pieces = 0;

        foreach($board_to_use[$move] as $column_key => $column_space)
        {
            // check if you are at the edge of an empty row
            if(!array_key_exists(($location_of_new_pieces + 1), $board_to_use[$move]) && $column_space == '_')
            {
                $board_to_use[$move][$location_of_new_pieces] = ($active_players_move == 1) ? 'x' : 'o';
                break;
            }

            // check if the next place has stuff in it too
            if($column_space != '_')
            {
                // check the edge of the board to make sure that exists
                if(array_key_exists(($location_of_new_pieces - 1), $board_to_use))
                {
                    $board_to_use[$move][$location_of_new_pieces - 1] = ($active_players_move == 1) ? 'x' : 'o';
                    break;
                } else {
                    echo "well fuck...1"; exit;
                }
            }

            $location_of_new_pieces++;
        }

        return $board_to_use;
    }

    public function move_possible($move, $game_board)
    {
        // check that this move is not going to fall out of the board
        if($game_board[$move][0] != "_")
        {
            return FALSE;
        } else {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }

    public function check_for_winner_or_draw($game_array, $active_player_move)
    {
        $present_possible_winner    = "";
        $count_to_win               = 0;
        $game_not_a_draw            = FALSE;

        for($i = 0; $i < $this->board_length; $i++)
        {
            for($j = 0; $j < $this->board_width; $j++)
            {
                // start checking for a winner
                if($game_array[$i][$j] != "_")
                {
                    $present_possible_winner = $game_array[$i][$j]; 

                    // check for a winner horizontally
                    for($x = 0; $x < 4; $x++)
                    {
                        if($j+$x < $this->board_width)
                        {
                            if($game_array[$i][$j+$x] == $present_possible_winner)
                            {
                                $count_to_win = $count_to_win + 1;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if($count_to_win > 3)
                    {
                        return $present_possible_winner;    // this player has won
                    } else {
                        $count_to_win = 0;
                    }

                    // check for a winner horizontally
                    for($y = 0; $y < 4; $y++)
                    {
                        if($i+$y < $this->board_width)
                        {
                            if($game_array[$i+$y][$j] == $present_possible_winner)
                            {
                                $count_to_win = $count_to_win + 1;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if($count_to_win > 3)
                    {
                        return $present_possible_winner;    // this player has won
                    } else {
                        $count_to_win = 0;
                    }

                    // check for a winner up to down diagonal
                    for($z = 0; $z < 4; $z++)
                    {
                        if(($i+$z < $this->board_width) && ($j+$z < $this->board_length))
                        {
                            if($game_array[$i+$z][$j+$z] == $present_possible_winner)
                            {
                                $count_to_win = $count_to_win + 1;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if($count_to_win > 3)
                    {
                        return $present_possible_winner;    // this player has won
                    } else {
                        $count_to_win = 0;
                    }

                    // check for a winner down to up diagonal
                    for($w = 0; $w < 4; $w++)
                    {
                        if(($i+$w < $this->board_width) && ($j-$w >= 0))
                        {
                            if($game_array[$i+$w][$j-$w] == $present_possible_winner)
                            {
                                $count_to_win = $count_to_win + 1;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if($count_to_win > 3)
                    {
                        return $present_possible_winner;    // this player has won
                    } else {
                        $count_to_win = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        // check for a drawed game and return accordingly
        for($i = 0; $i < $this->board_length; $i++)
        {
            for($j = 0; $j < $this->board_width; $j++)
            {
                if($game_array[$i][$j] == "_")
                {
                    $game_not_a_draw = TRUE;
                }
            }
        }

        if(!$game_not_a_draw)
        {
            return -1;
        }

        return 0;
    }


            // this is a private debugging function that I wrote for this script
    public function debug($value = NULL, $name = NULL, $exit = NULL)
    {
        if(!empty($name))
        {
            echo $name . "<br />";              
        }
        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($value);
        echo "</pre>";

        if($exit)
        {
            exit;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried it with `error_reporting(E_ALL);`? Have you checked your server's logs?

Comment: In the "check for possible moves" loop, add a function that writes `$i`, `$depth`, and `$depth_limit` to a file, and see what that looks like.

Comment: Checked the logs. I'll run error_reposting()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found it: The calculate ai move had an infinite loop in it...

```
 //choose your move
    for($u = 0; $u < $this->board_length; $u)
    {
        if($move_weight_array[$u][0] == 1)
        {
            return $prime_game_board[$u];               
        }
    }
```

Should be

```
 //choose your move
    for($u = 0; $u < $this->board_length; $u++)
    {
        if($move_weight_array[$u][0] == 1)
        {
            return $prime_game_board[$u];               
        }
    }
```

Back to work for me...